How to disable "buffer size remaining" [r#] number on the Nikon D5600?
The Nikon D5600 r# number is not interesting to me. Is there a way to disable it?

This seems to appear when the user shoots in Burst Mode (Continuous L / Continuous H modes). I suppose the buffer size is interesting for most users using this mode. If it's not interesting for you, there doesn't seem to be a way to disable it; you'll just have to train your brain to ignore it.

Ignore it or use a single shot mode instead of shooting in Burst Mode.
